# Using maxBounds to stop panning in Leaflet with angular-leaflet-directive

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

Now that I have my AngularJS application running, I'm trying to restrict LeafletJS map panning as described in [this Mapbox document](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/maxbounds/).  The issue is that I am using angular-leaflet-directive and my existing code is written to create the map using the leaflet directive in my AngularJS template.  So the existing map is defined in this fashion:

```html
<leaflet id="mymap" markers="markers" center="center" width="100%" height="380px"></leaflet>
```

How do I getBounds() and setMaxBounds() in a situation like this, where I never explicitly did a call to new L.map('leaflet', {...}))?

Comment: your snippet does not work properly

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Without supporting code in the controller, the leaflet directive wouldn't work.  I am simply attempting to illustrate how I am using the leaflet directive in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bounds` and `maxBounds` properties could be set via `angular-leaflet-directive` using `maxBounds` and `bounds` directives respectively, for example:

```
<leaflet markers="markers" maxbounds="boundsInfo" bounds="boundsInfo"></leaflet>
```

where bounds should be specified in the following format:

```
$scope.boundsInfo = {'northEast': {'lat': 40.774, 'lng': -74.125},'southWest': {'lat': 40.712, 'lng': -74.227}};
```

**Example**

```js
angular.module("demoapp", ["leaflet-directive"])
    .controller("CustomizedMarkersController", ['$scope','leafletData', function ($scope, leafletData) {

       
        $scope.boundsInfo = {'northEast': {'lat': 40.774, 'lng': -74.125},'southWest': {'lat': 40.712, 'lng': -74.227}};
        $scope.markers = [];

        leafletData.getMap().then(function (map) {
         
            console.log(map.getBounds());
        });

    }]);
```

```css
.angular-leaflet-map {
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.2/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoapp" ng-controller="CustomizedMarkersController">
    <leaflet markers="markers" maxbounds="boundsInfo" bounds="boundsInfo" maxZoom="19" minZoom="10"></leaflet>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't respond sooner to your answer.  I really appreciate the help.

In my application, I'm drawing the map with a single marker in the center representing the main point of interest.  How do I calculate the northEast and southWest bounds given a known center point?